# Contingency testing in geographic data with the issue of independence?

Tags: spatial, contingency-tables, independence

How can I test contingency between two variables in geographic data with the issue of independence? I have a column of fire frequency and a column of vegetation change but do not think a simple chi square contingency table is valid as the data is not sampled independently, but is the whole area (by satellite)?

Comment: It's a good question, but it will become easier to understand and answer if you would edit the post to explain the nature of your data and how they were collected and processed.

Comment: The data was from Landsat imagery, so effectively 2 rasters producing a third raster with fire frequency (a number) and change (one of 3 outcomes).